# Intel Fortran Composer 2011 and Linux Mint 12

Tags: linux, fortran, intel, linux-mint

I'm using Intel Fortran Composer 2011 on a Linux Mint 12 system.
Every time (and for every user) I restart the computer I need to set the environment variables.

> source /opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/bin/compilervars.sh
>   intel64

Is there any way to make it automatic for all users?

Sorry my poor english.
Thanks,
CP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a file under `/etc/profile.d` with the following content (e.g name it `intel.sh`)

```
#!/bin/sh

source /opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. I tried to run the file directly and return was: </etc/profile.d/intel.sh: 1: source: not found
>

Comment: I did it. However the problem persists. = /