# How do I run Intel Fortran Composer XE after installing it?

Tags: linux, fortran

I installed the Intel Fortran Composer XE from [this link](http://software.intel.com/en-us/non-commercial-software-development) on my Debian Linux system, which includes the Intel Fortran Compiler. I installed it to `opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080`, but now I'm not sure how to run it. I followed the instructions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9845724/2766558) to install the environment variables, but now I'm trying to run the IDE.

Does Intel Fortran on Linux not come with an IDE? On Windows everyone talks about integrating it with Visual Studio, so do I need to integrate it with Eclipse (somehow?), or what? Can someone point me to resources telling me about this? I don't see information anywhere, so I feel like... I'm just supposed to know and that this is a really stupid question. What *is* the composer if not an IDE? Is the composer different from the compiler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to source two files into your environment (and possibly specify your architecture)

```
source /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
source /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/bin/compilervars_arch.sh intel64
```

To find out what architectures are supported run

```
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/bin/compilervars.sh
```

without any arguments

You can create a file named `/etc/profile.d/intel.sh`, and insert these lines into it. after editing you should log out and log in back again, then try

```
which icc
which ifort

echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

To see if your environment knows the correct location of everything

If you cannot edit files under /etc (no super user privileges), just add these two 'source' lines into your ~/.bashrc, then log out and log in again

Answer (score 3):

Just put `source compilervars.sh` to jour `.profile` or `/etc/profile.d`. No need to create symlinks for everything.

As to IDE, there is no own IDE in Intel Composer. People even don't use IDE's that much on Linux, when they are used to `vi`, `emacs`, `kate` or whatever.

Intel Parallel Studio comes with eclipse plug-in for C++, but not for Fortran. You may use  [Photran](http://www.eclipse.org/photran/) as a Fortran Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 2):

In response to Part A about *using* ifort, you need to create a symbolic link to `ifort`:

```
ln -s path/to/ifort /usr/bin/ifort
```

Then you should be able to just type `ifort code.f90` into your terminal and have an executable.

As to Part B about an IDE: my $0.02 is that they as a whole are a dime a dozen. I usually use a text editor or terminal (I'm a `nano` user). I don't know squat about Intel's IDE, but Steve Lionel has been hanging around SO lately, so he might be able to better serve you on this note.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the symlink. Is that any different from running `compilevars.sh`? Whatever the case it worked so I'll probably stick with that. Does Intel even *have* an IDE for Linux?

Comment: Running the `compilervars.sh` command will enable you to run `ifort` from *that* terminal. Adding in the link allows your IDEs to use `ifort`. I think that the Parallel Studio is available for Linux, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: IMO, simply linking `ifort` is a bad idea, because you miss all the libraries.

Comment: @Stefan: I have never run into that problem in doing this.

Comment: @KyleKanos I used mixed programming in the past (C <> Fortran). These programs require `libifcore` which is not in the standard paths and is maybe not immediately available in your case.

Comment: @Stefan: I do not use `ifcore`, but a quick test (one that includes the line `use ifcore`) shows that it does indeed compile with only the symbolic link.

Comment: @KyleKanos I see the problem... I compiled my mixed program with `icc` and had to link `libifcore` explicitly. I did this dynamically. `ifort` seems to link this library as a static library, per default (see `ifort test.f90 -v`). You should not be able to compile and *execute* your program with `-shared-intel`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an excellent article by Intel on [Using Intel® C++ Compiler with the Eclipse* IDE on Linux*](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-c-compiler-for-linux-using-intel-compilers-with-the-eclipse-ide-pdf). Hope this helps. I'm amazed people think they can get by with no debugger on Linux. They must be writing some very flat, mono-threaded code. Also, here's a good expose on the features of the debugger. It's about time SOMEBODY went beyond GDB and provided a reasonable debugging environment in Linux. [Intel® Debugger for Linux* (IDB)](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/idb-linux)